# Open XLSX file obtained by HTTP.get

Tags: julia

I can open an XLSX file off the web like this:

```
tnlret = HTTP.get(tnlurl)
write("tnlxlsx.xlsx", tnlret.body)
tnlxl = XLSX.openxlsx("tnlxlsx.xlsx", mode="r")
```

but I can't do this:

```
tnlret = HTTP.get(tnlurl)
io=IOBuffer()
write(io, tnlret.body)
tnlxl = XLSX.openxlsx(io, mode="r")
close(io)
```

The latter produces:

```
ERROR: LoadError: input is not a valid XLSX file.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(s::String)
   @ Base .\error.jl:35
 [2] check_for_xlsx_file_format(source::IOBuffer, label::String)
   @ XLSX C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\XLSX\we7i6\src\read.jl:22
 [3] check_for_xlsx_file_format
   @ C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\XLSX\we7i6\src\read.jl:11 [inlined]
 [4] XLSX.XLSXFile(source::IOBuffer, use_cache::Bool, is_writable::Bool)
   @ XLSX C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\XLSX\we7i6\src\types.jl:289
 [5] open_or_read_xlsx(source::IOBuffer, read_files::Bool, enable_cache::Bool, read_as_template::Bool)
   @ XLSX C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\XLSX\we7i6\src\read.jl:196
 [6] openxlsx(source::IOBuffer; mode::String, enable_cache::Bool)
   @ XLSX C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\XLSX\we7i6\src\read.jl:172
 [7] top-level scope
   @ c:\Users\TGebbels\OneDrive - ...\Read360Gjson.jl:33
in expression starting at c:\Users\TGebbels\OneDrive - ...\Read360Gjson.jl:33
```

The file is a public file at:
`https://www.tnlcommunityfund.org.uk/media/data/grants/2021_22_v5.xlsx?mtime=20220608130305&focal=none`

Is it possible to open an XLSX file from the web without creating a disk file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After writing to `io`, its cursor is at the end, so while it contains data, anything reading from it will see it as empty. See the value of `ptr` below:

```
julia> write(io, tnlret.body)
3878550

julia> io
IOBuffer(data=UInt8[...], readable=true, writable=true, seekable=true, append=false, size=3878550, maxsize=Inf, ptr=3878551, mark=-1)
```

All that's necessary is to `seekstart(io)`, which will move the cursor back to the front.

```
julia> seekstart(io)
IOBuffer(data=UInt8[...], readable=true, writable=true, seekable=true, append=false, size=3878550, maxsize=Inf, ptr=1, mark=-1)

julia> XLSX.openxlsx(io, mode="r")
XLSXFile("IOBuffer(data=UInt8[...], readable=true, writable=true, seekable=true, append=false, size=3878550, maxsize=Inf, ptr=7254, mark=-1)") containing 1 Worksheet
            sheetname size          range        
-------------------------------------------------
              2021_22 13205x28      A1:AB13205
```

Comment: Thank you @BallpointBen.